# How to refer to particular variable in scope, using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have something like this in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="thread in threads">
    <div id="conversation-{{thread.id}}">
         <img src="{{ imageloader.image }}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in the controller (imageloader) function which set

```
imagesloader.image = 'path/to/image';
```

I need to refer only for particular imageloader.image not all of them, from all boxes. Because at this moment (i.e when I have 10 divs), and run controller function then image show up in all divs from repeat. Any ideas?

Comment: can you put code into pen or jsfiddle? I think I can help, but I need to know what you are trying to do specifically. You have 10 divs, all of which have an image and all images are visible. But you would want only one image to show on some user action. is that right?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Do you want to hide image for some threads? Under which conditions image should be shown?

Comment: @Todd excatcly, ng-repeat list 10 divs, but in the controller I would like to refer to one of them (i.e first) and set image, other images should be empty.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood you right...

I think best solution would be to add the path of the images as property to the threads array, then replace this

```
<img src="{{ imageloader.image }}"/>
```

with that

```
<img src="{{ thread.imageProperty }}"/>
```

Now if you want to change, or refer to one special image, you can get, or set your arrays image property, what will also affect the visible image on your website...

That way you can get/set a specific image by changing your array...

So you have one "datasource" per image instead of one "datasource" for all images

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've answered your own question by now, but I just got back to it, See if this is what you need.

Check this out:
**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3qwnf74s/2/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ImageCtrl" ng-init="images = [
  {title: 'kitty 1', url: 'http://aasdfasdf.my.imadge/f1'},
  {title: 'kitty 2', url: 'http://aasdfasdfb.my.image/f1'},
  {title: 'kitty 3', url: 'http://aasdfasfffdf.my.imagde/f1'}]">
      <div ng-repeat="(imageIndex, image) in images">
          <p>
              image: <i> {{image.title}} </i>
              <a href="#" ng-click="showImage(imageIndex)">Show Image</a>
          </p>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" ng-show="isShowing(imageIndex)" alt="{{image.title}}" />
      </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
function ImageCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.activeImageIndex;

    $scope.showImage = function(index) {
        $scope.activeImageIndex = index;
    };

    $scope.isShowing = function(index){
        return  $scope.activeImageIndex === index;
    };
};
```

Should be pretty easy... Just hope I understood correctly. lol.